# How to query an array in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets i have in a cell an array like `[27, https://www.example.com/page1.html, false, false, 1]`

How can i access its single parts with a formula?

I know a way through `=SPLIT()`, like `=split(split(A2,"["),",")` - but i would very like, if its possible, to access each part directly (each array has always the same amount of parts in my data set).

Maybe something like `=QUERY(query(A2,",",1))` - cell, divider, item number...? - Result is 27.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2,"[,]"),1)
```

- `SPLIT` by each of these characters `[,]`
- `INDEX` into the resulting array

Comment: Seems an idea i mentioned above has an exact implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to take the chance and propose a solution using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Basically, you can create your own **custom** function to accomplish this task.

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to **Tools** => **Script editor** from your spreadsheet file:
   [image: sample]
2. Clear the default *Code.gs* file, copy and paste this function and save the changes:

   ```
   function indexArray(arr,pos) {
      return array=arr.slice(1,-1).split(",")[pos-1]
   }
   ```

[image: script]

3. You are now able to access the `indexArray()` function from within your spreadsheet file. It accepts two arguments, the desired cell that contains the array and the position of the element you would like to access, starting from 1:

   ```
   =indexArray(A2,2)
   ```

[image: picture3]

For example, this will give you the **second** element of your array which is: `https://www.example.com/page1.html`.

Check these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) out if you need more information how custom functions work. They are pretty straightforward.